# Differences between three different ways using module.exports

Tags: node.js

I saw some people use different ways to create a class but I really don't know the differences or advantage using inline, use name or without function name. For example:

```
// Style 1. myclass.js. Use module.exports on a var
var myClass = function MyClass() {
   return something;
};

module.exports = myClass;

// Style 2. myclass.js. inline module.exports
module.exports = function MyClass() {
  return something;
};

// Style 3. myclass.js. inline module.export without function name
module.exports = function () {
   return something;
};
```

Usage:

```
var MyClass = require('myclass');
var classObj = new MyClass();
```

can anyone please explain or tell me the differences? I guess that using with function name will give much more info on stack trace?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Differences are small.

The difference between #1 and #2 is that `myClass` (the variable) can be used in other places within the module.

The difference between #2 and #3 is that the function has a name, and thus:

1. It is easier to use recursion if you want to (though not impossible in #3)
2. You get nicer-looking stack trace, as you said.

(Constructors are sometimes recursive, with the idiom that you can call them both with and without `new`, and they first check whether `this` is an instance of `MyClass` and if not call themselves recursively with `new`).

Comment: Thanks @Nitzan, in production environment, which one would you recommend? I would guess #1?

Comment: I personally use #1, but like I said the difference is small. All are "production worthy", it depends on your style I suppose.